# Maven - compilation error even if dependency path is correct

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I manually added a jar file under the repository of Maven located in .m2/repository.

[image]

Then I also edited the pom.xml file of the project

[image]

The jar file is also present under the Maven Dependencies

[image]

However, when I execute this command `mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies package` under the root directory of the source files, I would get this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project alexa-skills-kit-samples: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/jun/Desktop/Projects/WowLamp/alexa-skills-kit-java-master/samples/src/main/java/wowlampsmartcontrol/response/WowLampSmartControlResponse.java:[5,16] package org.json does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jun/Desktop/Projects/WowLamp/alexa-skills-kit-java-master/samples/src/main/java/wowlampsmartcontrol/http_request/WowLampSmartControlRequest.java:[7,16] package org.json does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jun/Desktop/Projects/WowLamp/alexa-skills-kit-java-master/samples/src/main/java/wowlampsmartcontrol/http_request/WowLampSmartControlRequest.java:[8,16] package org.json does not exist
[ERROR] /Users/jun/Desktop/Projects/WowLamp/alexa-skills-kit-java-master/samples/src/main/java/wowlampsmartcontrol/http_request/WowLampSmartControlRequest.java:[16,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class JSONObject
[ERROR] location: class http_request.WowLampSmartControlRequest
[ERROR] /Users/jun/Desktop/Projects/WowLamp/alexa-skills-kit-java-master/samples/src/main/java/wowlampsmartcontrol/http_request/WowLampSmartControlRequest.java:[30,62] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class JSONException
[ERROR] location: class http_request.WowLampSmartControlRequest
[ERROR] /Users/jun/Desktop/Projects/WowLamp/alexa-skills-kit-java-master/samples/src/main/java/wowlampsmartcontrol/http_request/WowLampSmartControlRequest.java:[67,51] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class JSONException
[ERROR] location: class http_request.WowLampSmartControlRequest
[ERROR] /Users/jun/Desktop/Projects/WowLamp/alexa-skills-kit-java-master/samples/src/main/java/wowlampsmartcontrol/response/WowLampSmartControlResponse.java:[127,24] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class JSONException
[ERROR] location: class response.WowLampSmartControlResponse
[ERROR] /Users/jun/Desktop/Projects/WowLamp/alexa-skills-kit-java-master/samples/src/main/java/wowlampsmartcontrol/http_request/WowLampSmartControlRequest.java:[32,37] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class JSONObject
[ERROR] location: class http_request.WowLampSmartControlRequest
[ERROR] /Users/jun/Desktop/Projects/WowLamp/alexa-skills-kit-java-master/samples/src/main/java/wowlampsmartcontrol/http_request/WowLampSmartControlRequest.java:[74,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class JSONObject
[ERROR] location: class http_request.WowLampSmartControlRequest
[ERROR] /Users/jun/Desktop/Projects/WowLamp/alexa-skills-kit-java-master/samples/src/main/java/wowlampsmartcontrol/http_request/WowLampSmartControlRequest.java:[74,45] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class JSONObject
[ERROR] location: class http_request.WowLampSmartControlRequest
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I don't understand why this happens.

----- UPDATE -----

I also tried adding the jar by command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/Users/jun/Desktop/Projects/WowLamp/alexa-skills-kit-java-master/samples/lib/java-json.jar -DgroupId=json.java -DartifactId=java-json -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

This is the hierarchy of the jar file after installation:

[image]

But still the same error occurs.

Comment: Use [`mvn install:install-file`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) to copy a jar in your local repo. This will create a pom file for you.

Comment: @ares Hi, I did what you said but still the same error. Already tried cleaning the project and update maven.

Comment: Are there any errors showing in eclipse. If you don't see any compilation errors in source file Check the *Markers* tab.

Comment: @ares there were no errors showing in eclipse. Uhm where can I see the Markers tab?

Comment: If you haven't changed the defaults and in Java or JavaEE perspective, then Markers tab should be the first tab at the bottom of screen among other tabs such as properties, servers, console etc.

Comment: @ares my first tab is the "Problems" tab. I don't know if this is the same as the markers tab that you said. But I don't see any errors in here. only bunch of warnings. But, none of the warnings are related to maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the jar using following command, rather than manually copying it into repository.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=java-json-1.0.jar -DgroupId=json.java \
-DartifactId=java-json -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

You can consult the maven [doc](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) for further details.

Comment: Hi, I did this still the same error and I also tried cleaning the project and update maven.

Comment: First remove json  folder from repository, run the command and share the view of repository

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I just happened to edit the wrong .pom file.